# A problem about chance

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I can't really think of a more definitive title. I have a problem about chances or probably combinations (I'm not very good at math).

The problem is: If there is an event that occurs 2 times in a year and a second event that occurs once in every year and a half - what are the odds of those events both occurring in the same day? Additionally how many years would it take to eventually have the events occur?

I suppose the second part of the problem would be theoretical since there is never a guarantee with chances.

I have had my poor attempt at solving this but I can bet that most of it is probably nonsense so I guess I should just spare you but will provide if asked for in the comments.

Basically I figured I should calculate the probability of both events

$$ E_A = 2 / 365.25 = 0.0054757015742642 $$

$$ E_B = 1 / (365.25 * 1.5) = 0.0018252338580881 $$

Then the probability to have both events occur in the same day would be the product of the probabilities calculated above (for some reason).

$$ P = E_A * E_B = 0.0054757015742642 * 0.0018252338580881 = 9.994435910133329*10^{-6} $$

Then for the second part I figured I would multiply $P$ until it reaches 1 and then divide by 365.25 to get the result in years, which turned out to be (around) 100056 times, so

$$ 100056 / 365.25 = 273 $$

But that is definitely not a mathematical solution, assuming the first part is correct, which most probably isn't.

Comment: What was your attempt to solve the first question ?

Comment: @calculus Updated.

Comment: Provided your events are independent, your analysis looks essentially right to me.  The "rate" at which events of types A and B occur (per day) is as you've computed them, and assuming independence, you can determine the rate of the joint event, and the expected time (in days) for the joint event is one over that rate.

Comment: Note that although the mean time to the next joint event is about 27 years, that time has quite a wide spread to it, and the most likely time is still in the immediate future.  It has a so-called geometric distribution, meaning that the probability of the next joint event happening on any given day falls off like radioactive decay.

Comment: @BrianTung so you mean to tell me that somehow what I thought was (about) right? Also I had a slight mistake, the result in years is 273 not 27.

Comment: I'd agree that the reasoning is fairly sound. There are a few subtleties though. For example, can the first event occur twice in one day? And is it equally likely that the first event occurs for all days of the year? Also, the probability that both occur on the same day has two interpretations: are we talking about $any$ day or a specific day? The chances are higher if we don't care about the particular day. Edit: I'd also just say that the assumption of independent events, while done often in theory, could be disastrous in practice. Many things in the real world are subtly linked.

Comment: @ColmBhandal I'm sorry the problem was not definitive enough - the first event cannot occur twice in one day and they can occur in *any* day.

Comment: It's a good problem. Probability is a strange and subtle concept. For example, if the first event must occur exactly twice in a calendar year, and it's $30^{th}$ December and the event hasn't occurred yet all year, we know for definite that it will occur today and tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the length of the year is $L$ days, every day we have a probability $\frac{2}{L}$ that the first event occurs, and a probability $\frac{2}{3L}$ that the second event occurs. Assuming they are independent, they both occur with probability $\frac{4}{3L^2}$. Since the expected value of a [geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with success probability $p$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, we expect to have to wait:
$$\frac{3}{4}L^2 = 100055.671875 $$
days to see both events occur the same day, i.e. a bit less than 274 years. So your computations, together with a proper explanation, are just fine.